# Why \textfloatsep has no effect on figures/tables?

Tags: floats

I have quite a few floats(figures/tables) in my document.
Now I want to enlarge the (below and above) separation between a float and the main text.

I resort to `\textfloatsep`. I hope to set it once for all.

But it has no effect. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}

\setlength\textfloatsep{5em}

\title{test}
\begin{document}
This is a test table.

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}cl@{}}
\caption{test table}\tabularnewline
\toprule
col1 & col2\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
1 & 2\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

This is test figure.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{test.png}
\caption{test figure}
\end{figure}

End of the document.
\end{document}
```

No matter what value I set, the output does not change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\textfloatsep` is the separation between the top and bottom float areas and the main text body, but `h` floats are separated by `\intextsep`

`longtable` is not a float and so is not affected by either parameter. (It has separate `\LTpre` and `\LTpost` length parameters.)

Comment: I see. `\intextsep` works, as well as `\LTpre` and `\LTpost`. But when I add `\usepackage{etoolbox}\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\fontsize{10.5pt}{10.5pt}\selectfont\setlength\LTpre{5em}\setlength\LTpost{5em}}`, the separation does not work, while the font size takes effect.

Comment: why would you want to do that rather than just setting LTpre to 5em? also \fontsize{10.5pt}{10.5pt} is very tight spacing, does that work at all? (it depends on the font I suppose). In any case that is a different question.

Comment: Well, the font size for the tables is different from that of the main text, and I want to set it once for all. So I put the settings (including `\LTpre` and `\LTpost`) in  `\AtBeginEnvironment`.